# How to fix "device/asus/msm8916-common/ms8916.mk does not exist" error while compiling Atomic OS from source?

Tags: android, custom-rom

I have recently started learning comoiling rom from source. I have followed this guide https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=54118852&postcount=9 to make the the lineage device tree(for my device) compatible with Atomic OS. But after executing lunch I get the following error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRv2y.jpg

Please point out my mistakes and tell me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

> device/asus/msm8916-common/ms8916.mk

does not exist 
because it should be **`msm8916.mk`** and not `ms8916.mk`.

Hope this solves your error.